# About enable/disable by conditional values in ansible yaml manifest

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want a variable on Ansible to be active or passive depending on the condition.

I am using the role "davidwittman.redis". I'm setting up a redis cluster. I need to run a single yml file by deploying it to 3 servers at the same time. I can't distribute "yml" files separately.

I have a simple setup configuration below. Here, I want to activate the "redis_slaveof" value on all other servers, except the master server, depending on the condition.

In other words, I want the "redis_slaveof" value I selected to not be active on the master server, but to have this value active on the other 2 servers.

How can I do this, do you have any suggestions ?

my main ansible configuration;

```
> - name: Redis Replication Slave Installations   hosts: localhost
> 
>   pre_tasks:
>   - name: check redis server1
>     shell: "cat /etc/hosts |grep redis |awk '{print $2}' |sed -n 1p"
>     register: server01
> 
>   - name: check redis server2
>     shell: "cat /etc/hosts |grep redis |awk '{print $2}' |sed -n 2p"
>     register: server02
> 
>   - name: check redis server3
>     shell: "cat /etc/hosts |grep redis |awk '{print $2}' |sed -n 3p"
>     register: server03
> 
>   roles:
>     - role: davidwittman.redis
> 
>       vars:
>         - redis_version: 6.2.6
>         - redis_bind: 0.0.0.0
>         - redis_port: 6379
>         - redis_service_name: redis-service
>         - redis_protected_mode: "no"
>         - redis_config_file_name: "redis.conf"
> 
> #        - redis_slaveof: "{{ server01.stdout }} 6379"
```

I tried the following;

- I added extra task and "import_role". I put a when condition in it. If my server01 value and server local hostname value are not the equal, enable this role. Thus, I thought that it would activate this value on other servers except the master server.But it didn't work, added it on all servers. I saw the following error in the logs.
  "[WARNING]: flush_handlers task does not support when conditional"

> ```
>  tasks:
>   - name: test
>     import_role:
>       name: davidwittman.redis
>     vars:
>       redis_slaveof: "{{ server01.stdout }} 6379"
>     when: '"{{ (server01.stdout) }}" != "{{ ansible_hostname }}"'
> ```

- I added the when condition to the main role as above and made it to two different roles in a single yml. This method also failed.

> ```
> - role: davidwittman.redis
>   when: '"{{ (server01.stdout) }}" != "{{ ansible_hostname }}"'
> ```

- I defined the "if/else" condition as follows in the variable. But although it seems to have worked, it still gave the error "does not support when conditional". Added it to all servers as well.

> - redis_slaveof: "{%if '{{ (server01.stdout) }} != {{ ansible_hostname }}' %} {{ '{{ (server01.stdout) }} 6379' }} {% else %} {{ '' }} {% endif %}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to run a role differently, based on variables.

In your playbook do not use

```
roles:
  - role: davidwittman.redis
```

but rather do

```
tasks:
  - name: Pass variables to role
    include_role:
      name: myrole
    vars:
      rolevar1: value from task
```

This is executed after roles but now you can add `when` expressions:

```
tasks:
  - name: Pass variables to role
    include_role:
      name: myrole
    vars:
      rolevar1: value from task
    when: ansible_hostname = "server1"

  - name: Pass variables to role
    include_role:
      name: myrole
    vars:
      rolevar1: value from task
      additionalrolevar: whatever
    when: ansible_hostname != "server1"
```